# For every prime $p$ and a fixed integer $k$, are there infinitely many values of $n$ such that $p$, $p^n+k$, $kp^n+1$ are all primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is similar to my last question, but may or may not be the case:

For every prime $p$ and a fixed integer $k$, are there infinitely many values of $n$ such that $p$, $p^n+k$, and $kp^n+1$ are all primes? All except $p$ being prime are uncertain to be prime infinitely, especially all three conditions at once. I don't think this belongs to Dickinson's conjecture either. Help on this appreciated. (Modular restrictions on $k$ are excluded.)

Comment: If $k,p$ are odd, then $kp^n +1$ is even and thus not prime.

Comment: I know that, I am only looking for $k$ which does not have modular restrictions above.

Comment: Well, then include that in your post.

Comment: http://www.utm.edu/staff/caldwell/preprints/2to100.pdf implies that for every positive integer $b$, there are numbers $k$ such that $kb^n+1$ is composite for all $n$ (but no prime divides all of them).

Comment: Thank for the clarification. Do you fix the prime $p$ and then ask if there are infinitely $n$? Or do the $p$ vary too?

Comment: Fix both $p$ and $k$ and ask if there are infinitely many values of $n$ such that $p$, $p^n+k$, $kp^n+1$ are all prime. Example: $p=2$ and $k=3$, Are there infinitely many values of $n$ such that $2$, $2^n+3$ and $3*2^n+1$ are all primes (use the same value of $n$ for the last two conditions.)